# How would I take a variable from a string and reassign its value?

Tags: string-manipulation

If I have string={a,b,c}, where a=1, b=2, and c=3, how would I reassign a value to variable "a" without directly typing  a = _?  If I type string[[1]], the out put is "1". How would I generate the letter "a" instead?

Comment: You'd need to "quote" the symbol names in some way, e.g. by storing them as `Hold[a,b,c]` instead of `{a,b,c}`.

Comment: If you want to display the letter a you can use `SymbolName`.

Comment: Try this: list = {"a", "b", "c"};Evaluate[ToExpression[list]] = {1, 2, 3};